# External monitor resolution is 1024x768 (cvt+xrandr distorts the output)

Tags: graphics, resolution, hp, monitor, xrandr

I have a HP 2009v LCD monitor with VGA input which is plugged to my laptop with Intel graphics card. Windows recognizes the maximum resolution (`1600x900`) and displays the desktop correctly. Ubuntu 12.04, on the other hand, fails to recognize the maximum resolution and lists only `1024x768` and `800x600`.

I tried to add a mode manually using `cvt 1600x900` and `xrandr --newmode`. When I switch to this new mode, though, the output gets distorted and the visible area shrinks to the 2/3 of the actual screen.

I suspect that the mode parameters (generated by `cvt`) are incorrect for this specific monitor but I don't have a clue how to correct them.

Is there a way to guess these parameters? Can I steal them from Windows drivers? Is there any other solution that does not require fiddling these numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-r` option with `cvt` worked! I don't know what it means but it was the only command line option so I gave it a shot. With this option, `cvt` produced different parameters and those parameters produced a very crisp (even more than Windows) image.